# Collecting sink materialized values as source

Tags: scala, akka-stream

Is there a better way (ie. by removing the `Materializer` constraint) to implement the following method:

```
import akka.NotUsed
import akka.stream.Materializer
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Keep, Sink, Source}

def assemble[A, B, C](source: Source[A, NotUsed])
                     (f: A => Source[B, NotUsed], g: A => Sink[B, C])
                     (implicit m: Materializer): Source[C, NotUsed] = {

  source.map(a => f(a).toMat(g(a))(Keep.right).run())
}
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially you are after materializing a bunch of graphs and create a `Source` of their materialized values.
I don't see a way of doing this without a `Materializer` parameter.

In case it helps, you can write your method in a more compact fashion as

```
source.map(a => f(a).runWith(g(a)))
```